# How to copy rows of only values from a worksheet to a column in a second worksheet

Tags: vba

I have a sheet "Creation" where I need data to go. I have second sheet "Abomination" where I need to pull data from. In Abomination I have a row data starting at D6.  n Creation I have a column with the first cell B2, where the data from Abomination needs to go. Both the Row in Abomination and the Column in Creation will vary in terms of cells. Basically Abomination is one of many sheets in the same format where I will be pulling data from. This code only pulls the last cell value from abomination:

```
Sub Bob()

Dim Creation As Worksheet
Dim Abomination As Worksheet
Dim destRange As Range
Dim sourcerange As Range
Set Creation = Worksheets("Creation")
Set Abomination = Worksheets("Abomination")

With Abomination

Set sourcerange = .Range("D6").End(xlToRight)

End With

With Creation

Set destRange = .Range("B2")

End With

sourcerange.Copy

destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good article on how to use loops in VBA: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Set sourcerange = .Range("D6").End(xlToRight)
```

using End() doesn't *extend* the range from D6, it just moves to a different range mimicking pressing `Ctrl+right arrow`

Maybe you want something like:

```
Set sourcerange = .Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D6").End(xlToRight))
```

Comment: That is awesome! it works beautifully! I just wish understood how it works.

Comment: Could I say that .Range(.Range("D6"), is specifying the start and .Range("D6").End(xlToRight)) is saying stop when you get to the last value? I just want to learn it in a way that makes sense to me. Thanks again!

Comment: More like "all cells between and including these two cells"